# OpenStreetMap not returning postcode for certain queries

Tags: openstreetmap, nominatim

I am using `https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search` and it seems that some queries aren't returning `postcode` inside of `address` object for some reason and others do.

For example:

`https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?countrycodes=us&addressdetails=1&format=json&q=47711`

returns the `postcode`, but this does not:

`https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?countrycodes=us&addressdetails=1&format=json&q=evansville`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evansville has more than one postcode. Which one should nominatim return? 47711 is just one part of Evansville, but Evansville has many more postcodes.

A postcode can only be returned if it is exact as in one postcode for the query.

So e.g. if you query the North High School in Evansville as in here: https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?countrycodes=us&addressdetails=1&format=json&q=north%20high%20school%20evansville you'll get a postcode.